# Visualforce wizard in Community

Tags: visualforce, community, profile, pagereference

I tried apply VF Wizard( 1 Controller, 3 VF Page ) to Community but not work..

the Community is for guest user

until C page work done, they don't have to login

I applied...

- 1. Guest user profile setting ( VF access, Apex access )
- 2. set Community login page as A ( VF Page )
- 3. write without sharing on Apex code

expected result was A -> B -> C  page and Share Global variable value.

but at B page, global variable value was null..page seems like redirect

and when the error occurred, get back to A page

why they can't sharing variable value ???

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If set redirect to true**, a redirect is performed through a **client side redirect**. This type of redirect performs an HTTP GET request, and flushes the view state, which uses POST. **If set to false**, the **redirect is a server-side** forward that preserves the view state if and only if the target page uses the same controller and contains the proper subset of extensions used by the source page.

Something Like this, that preserve the view State of the page

```
public PageReference redirectPageB()
{
    PageReference pageB= Page.pageB;
    pageB.setRedirect(false);
    return pageB;
}

public PageReference redirectPageC()
{
    PageReference pageC= Page.pageC;
    pageC.setRedirect(false);
    return pageC;
}
```